# Iterating through folders for specific files in BASH

Tags: bash

I'm new to coding and am trying to iterate through folders to find a specific file (called the same thing in each folder). I have 3 folders (CONTROL, GROUP1, and GROUP2). Each folder has 2 subfolders in it from the folder names (2 3 4 5 6 7. Each subfolder has a file in it with the subfolder name such as 2_diff.nii or 3_diff.nii. I'd like the code to go into each folder, find the subfolders, and then perform an analysis of the file in there. The problem is that my code seems to be looking for each subfolder in each main folder and each main folder only has 2 of the subfolders out of (2 3 4 5 6 7). Any tips would be greatly appreciated - thank you!!

```
Folders=(CONTROL GROUP1 GROUP2)
SubFolders=(2 3 4 5 6 7)

data_source=/Users/sheena/Desktop/test/

for j in ${Folders[@]}; do
  cd ${data_source}/${j}/
  for i in ${SubFolders[@]}; do
    fslroi ${i}_diff.nii ${i}_nodif 0 1 #I want to analyze the file <subfolder>_diff.nii and name the output as <subfolder>_nodif.nii
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I understand your question is that in each of the directories `CONTROL`, `GROUP1`, and `GROUP1` there are 2 files of the form `x_diff.nii` where `x` is a digit between 2 and 7. At least that's how I read your code.

You don't in advance know which two digits there are.

The easiest way I see it is to run through all possible `SubFolders` like you do, but use the `continue` statement early to jump to the next if it doesn't exist:

```
Folders=(CONTROL GROUP1 GROUP2)
SubFolders=(2 3 4 5 6 7)

data_source=/Users/sheena/Desktop/test/

for j in ${Folders[@]}; do
  cd ${data_source}/${j}/
  for i in ${SubFolders[@]}; do
    if [[ ! -e ${i}_diff.nii ]]; then
      continue
    fi
    fslroi ${i}_diff.nii ${i}_nodif 0 1
  done
done
```

You could replace the `if` clause above with a single line:

```
  for i in ${SubFolders[@]}; do
    [[ -e ${i}_diff.nii ]] || continue
    fslroi ${i}_diff.nii ${i}_nodif 0 1
  done
```

But I find the more expressive `if` - `fi` block easier to read and understand, and that's important too.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. I wasn't familiar with the continue command, but it worked beautifully!!

Comment: Now that I look at it, I wonder why I haven't done the obvious and placed the `fslroi` command line inside the `if` block. Then I wouldn't have needed the `continue`. Anyway, if it works, it works.